# error in loading r packages

Tags: r, bioconductor

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("BSgenome")
```

> 'no packages in repository (no internet connection?)' while trying
>     http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.2/bioc, trying http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.1/bioc
>   Error: no packages in repository (no internet connection?)

I tried using other available solutions but cannot sort the issue. Please help.

Thanks

I got this when I used `sessionInfo()`

> Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'uname' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'

Comment: I assume you are connected to the internet. Can you edit your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I got this when I used sessionInfo()
Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
  cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'uname' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'

Comment: Quit R (don't save the workspace), restart, and then try sourcing above command again. Also, don't put code output in comments. Always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19101849) your question to include additional details.

Comment: I cannot quit R because I have large files scanned into environment which I will be needing for further coding. I have uploaded two files of approximately 18GB each. I guess the problem is arising because of that.

Comment: Manually save critical files/objects (e.g. using `save`), then quit. There is obviously something wrong with your current R session if `sessionInfo()` complains about not being able to allocate memory. The issue with `biocLite` is likely to be related to that.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers for helping me figure out the issue. The only problem is that the files take too long to get loaded again into the environment and I want to avoid doing that. I am trying to install the packages on other R session and then call the library in this one. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me... so it looks like the problem is not in the sourcing or the code you're trying to load. Check and see if R can detect your internet connection:

```
system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE)
```